# Battery swollen on a doorbell device - can I replace it with a capacitor?

Tags: batteries, capacitor, repair, camera

I have an Amcrest AD410 doorbell camera. I noticed the bottom of the device is open/cracked. When I investigated inside, I found the battery is swollen. I couldn't find replacement for the battery, can I use capacitors instead? What specifications are the best fit for the capacitor?

The device takes either 24V AC, 24V DC or 12V DC.

[image]

Comment: Most probably not. The best supercapacitors have very high leakage and low usable capacity compared to a battery. What battery runtime do you expect?

Comment: @winny the device is connected 24/7 to a 12V DC power source, so I assumed they added the battery to act as a capacitor to provide a stable current

Comment: If you only need to fool it to make some “battery error” message to go away, perhaps you could get by with a capacitor.

Comment: Does the device need the battery at all?

Comment: @Jens I removed it, and the device still works, although I'm not sure if there're other circuits in the device that uses the battery's voltage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

That battery is far bigger than any capacitor you're likely to be able to buy.  A very rough calculation suggests that 0.2Ah with a drop of voltage of 1V is roughly equivalent to a 720F capacitor (0.2Ah = 720As).  And it would need to be a capacitor rated for 5V.

The battery is probably intended as a back up if the power fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can find this battery online just Google "battery 652023". It is a china exclusive part. You can also find another model substitute such as the 652025. I found it on ali express for less then $10 USD shipped. If using a sub battery model just make sure the physical battery size fits the space. I also installed the lorex camera but I used it to replace the RCA video doorbell. The RCA video doorbell came with a power kit the small device [small box with two wires] that is installed on the mechanical chime. The function of the power kit is to make sure that there is enough power sent to your video doorbell to function properly. I suspect if you get a power kit adapter for your chime you can most likely bypass the battery function, but just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

This battery provides power when the button is pressed to complete the circuit via an internal relay so the chime rings. This circuit is completed for 3-7 seconds depending on the type of chime.

Finding a cap to store enough power for, let's say, a maximum of 10 seconds is very doable at 3.7 V. This would be FAR more reliable in cold/hot environments than a Li-ion battery.